# how to make navigation bar always appear on top and not scroll with content IOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I want to show navigation bar always visible on top while scrolling view . Kindly share code or sample if integrated. I want similar to facebook app navigation bar.

Comment: It always shows on top.I can't understand you.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to have navigation controller (Editor -> embed in -> Navigation Controller) while your view controller is selected.
Then use Show(e.g.Push) or Show Detail  as a storyboard segue kind.
Navigation bar will automatically appear.

This code hides bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

This shows bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

This code hides bar on swipe (like facebook app)

```
 self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

This should keep bar visible

```
 self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Comment: I don't want to hide , my concern is to always show a bar at top when user scroll view for ex. tableview user scroll come to 10 the cell but bar should be visible at top.

Answer (score 0):

When you set navigation controller, navigation bar will be always at the top as fixed. Your container starts from below the navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false
```

In fact you don't even have to write this code, because default functionality of navigation bar is visible always.